# How to disable TestResults folder in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio is generating a lot of empty folders in the `TestResults` subfolder of C# projects. Is there a way to disable it? I often delete more then 5k of them.

> ```
> Deploy_UserName 2017-10-31 18_13_17\
> Deploy_UserName 2017-10-31 18_57_15\
> Deploy_UserName 2017-10-31 19_18_32\
> Deploy_UserName 2017-10-31 19_19_47\
> Deploy_UserName 2017-10-31 19_20_21\
> Deploy_UserName 2017-10-31 19_20_26\
> Deploy_UserName 2017-11-02 16_33_32\
> Deploy_UserName 2017-11-02 16_34_11\
> Deploy_UserName 2017-11-02 16_45_12\
> Deploy_UserName 2017-11-02 16_45_39\
> Deploy_UserName 2017-11-02 17_09_55\
> ```

And this goes like that a few thousand tiems. All are empty.

I'm not sure if they actually slow VS down but I'd rather not have them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find a way how to disable it completely but at least an acceptable workaround. It moves them to a location that is more appropriate for them. It goes like that:

- Create a `.runsettings` file in your solution directory (you can give it any name - just keep the extension unchanged) with the following contents which will place the `TestResults` directory in the `%temp%` location of your machine. If you're not sure where it is, you can always check it in the command-line by calling `echo %test%` or just pick any other location.

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RunSettings>

    <RunConfiguration>    
      <ResultsDirectory>%temp%\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>    
    </RunConfiguration>

  </RunSettings>
  ```
- You now have to inform your test runner about it.

  - for MSTest users: go to `Test > Test Settings > Select Test Settings File`
  - for ReSharper users: go to `ReSharper > Options > Tools > Unit Testing > Ms Test` and pick the `Use specific test settings file`.

btw, these folders are created always and just won't be deleted if you interrupt the test-runner so it won't clean them up.

*(Inspired by [Configure unit tests by using a .runsettings file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2017))*

Comment: Nice, this way they're removed when deleting temp files in general.

Comment: I needed this to work for multiple users, and may have stumpled on how to avoid the folders... Apparently other users need admin to create folders for "Default" user, so setting the path to the temp folder of that user causes the folders to not be created;
<ResultsDirectory>C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>

Answer (score 1):

The `TestResults` folder can be created by `DeploymentItem` attributes in your project.

The `DeploymentItem` attribute will copy any file/directory you specify into the TestResults folder, and instead of running the tests under the `bin` directory, it will run them under the `TestResults` directory.

Keep in mind that the `DeploymentItem` attribute will change the context of *all* the tests, no matter if you specify it only on one test class. Once I removed all the `DeploymentItem` attributes from my project, there was no more `TestResults` folder.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883270/problems-with-deploymentitem-attribute